# How to insert record of a table_A table in its table_A_history table By trigger before update that record using stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I trying to store record of UserDetails table in UserHistory table by using trigger before update that particular record by using stored procedure in sql server.
Suppose a UserDetails contain a row ID, Name, Address, Contact, Email, Password. When this row is need to update then I want to insert this record in its History table by trigger before its update.

Comment: please specify the RDBMS you use. Triggers are highly vendor-specific DB-objects

Comment: Whoa! Text says "... in SQL Server". You tagged the question with many databases, none of them being SQL Server. I suggest you fix that (most possibly tags, not the question itself).